# How to find all cliques in an edge list

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I have a massive edge list file (~80 GB) of orthologous genes from an old OrthoMCL process. I would like to parse all cliques (a subgraph where all vertices share an edge with each other) out of the edge list and then collapse each clique to one line while ignoring reducdancy (Eg GeneA,GeneB <-> GeneB,GeneA) and self hits (GeneA <-> GeneA). I am experimenting with Python's networkX (find_cliques) but I am somewhat of an inexperienced programmer so I am not getting a desirable output. If anyone has any experience working with network structures could you please point me in the right direction?

Here is an example input:

```
GeneA,GeneA
GeneA,GeneB
GeneA,GeneC
GeneB,GeneA
GeneB,GeneB
GeneB,GeneC
GeneC,GeneA
GeneC,GeneB
GeneC,GeneC
GeneD,GeneD
GeneD,GeneE
GeneD,GeneF
GeneE,GeneD
GeneE,GeneE
GeneE,GeneF
GeneF,GeneD
GeneF,GeneE
GeneF,GeneF
GeneH,GeneH
GeneH,GeneI
GeneH,GeneJ
GeneH,GeneK
GeneH,GeneL
GeneH,GeneM
GeneH,GeneN
GeneH,GeneO
GeneH,GeneP
GeneH,GeneQ
GeneI,GeneH
GeneI,GeneI
GeneI,GeneJ
GeneI,GeneK
GeneI,GeneL
GeneI,GeneM
GeneI,GeneN
GeneI,GeneO
GeneI,GeneP
GeneI,GeneQ
GeneJ,GeneH
GeneJ,GeneI
GeneJ,GeneJ
GeneJ,GeneK
GeneJ,GeneL
GeneJ,GeneM
GeneJ,GeneN
GeneJ,GeneO
GeneJ,GeneP
GeneJ,GeneQ
GeneK,GeneH
GeneK,GeneI
GeneK,GeneJ
GeneK,GeneK
GeneK,GeneL
GeneK,GeneM
GeneK,GeneN
GeneK,GeneO
GeneK,GeneP
GeneK,GeneQ
GeneL,GeneH
GeneL,GeneI
GeneL,GeneJ
GeneL,GeneK
GeneL,GeneL
GeneL,GeneM
GeneL,GeneN
GeneL,GeneO
GeneL,GeneP
GeneL,GeneQ
GeneM,GeneH
GeneM,GeneI
GeneM,GeneJ
GeneM,GeneK
GeneM,GeneL
GeneM,GeneM
GeneM,GeneN
GeneM,GeneO
GeneM,GeneP
GeneM,GeneQ
GeneN,GeneH
GeneN,GeneI
GeneN,GeneJ
GeneN,GeneK
GeneN,GeneL
GeneN,GeneM
GeneN,GeneN
GeneN,GeneO
GeneN,GeneP
GeneN,GeneQ
GeneO,GeneH
GeneO,GeneI
GeneO,GeneJ
GeneO,GeneK
GeneO,GeneL
GeneO,GeneM
GeneO,GeneN
GeneO,GeneO
GeneO,GeneP
GeneO,GeneQ
GeneP,GeneH
GeneP,GeneI
GeneP,GeneJ
GeneP,GeneK
GeneP,GeneL
GeneP,GeneM
GeneP,GeneN
GeneP,GeneO
GeneP,GeneP
GeneP,GeneQ
GeneQ,GeneH
GeneQ,GeneI
GeneQ,GeneJ
GeneQ,GeneK
GeneQ,GeneL
GeneQ,GeneM
GeneQ,GeneN
GeneQ,GeneO
GeneQ,GeneP
GeneQ,GeneQ
GeneR,GeneR
GeneR,GeneS
GeneR,GeneT
GeneR,GeneU
GeneS,GeneR
GeneS,GeneS
GeneS,GeneT
GeneS,GeneU
GeneT,GeneR
GeneT,GeneS
GeneT,GeneT
GeneT,GeneU
GeneU,GeneR
GeneU,GeneS
GeneU,GeneT
GeneU,GeneU
GeneV,GeneW
GeneW,GeneV
GeneX,GeneX
GeneX,GeneY
GeneX,GeneZ
GeneY,GeneX
GeneY,GeneY
GeneY,GeneZ
GeneZ,GeneX
GeneZ,GeneY
GeneZ,GeneZ
```

Here is the desired output:

```
GeneA,GeneB,GeneC
GeneD,GeneE,GeneF
GeneH,GeneI,GeneJ,GeneK,GeneL,GeneM,GeneN,GeneO,GeneP,GeneQ
GeneR,GeneS,GeneT,GeneU
GeneV,GeneW
GeneX,GeneY,GeneZ
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What if the input is [this graph](https://imgur.com/a/mV02qwD), where both ABCD and ABCE are maximal cliques, but ABCDE is not a clique? Also, any subgraph of a clique is also a clique, but your example output doesn't list those cliques.

Comment: I don't think that would be an issue with this dataset as the original clustering mechanism was apparently very strict. If this were to come up though, I'd prefer to accept quasi-clique ABCDE over ABCD or ABCE. Would this be possible?

Comment: Possible, but it sounds like your graph may have important structure that simplifies the problem. Your example graph happens to be the disjoint union of 6 complete graphs (one K2, three K3s, a K4, and a K10), making its clique structure very simple. Is your real data guaranteed to have any similar properties?

Comment: I won't say guaranteed but that is certainly the expected result

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply try the function [find_cliques function](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.clique.find_cliques.html?highlight=clique#networkx-algorithms-clique-find-cliques)

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.read_edgelist("edgelist.txt",delimiter=',')

for clq in nx.clique.find_cliques(G):
    print clq
```

**Output**

```
[u'GeneX', u'GeneY', u'GeneZ']
[u'GeneP', u'GeneQ', u'GeneH', u'GeneI', u'GeneJ', u'GeneK', u'GeneL', u'GeneM', u'GeneN', u'GeneO']
[u'GeneR', u'GeneS', u'GeneT', u'GeneU']
[u'GeneV', u'GeneW']
[u'GeneA', u'GeneB', u'GeneC']
[u'GeneD', u'GeneE', u'GeneF']
```

There are several other [functions in networkx for manipulating cliques](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9.1/reference/algorithms.clique.html) if you want to take a look.